# Replace current binding source object with another object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm totally new to C# and WPF and I'm trying to do my best with the data binding. I have a MyClass which implements INotifyPropertyChanged; so everytime I change a property value, this is updated in my UI. Then I have bound the DataContext of a stackpanel to an object of MyClass. Like this:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind I do this:

```
item = new MyClass();
stackPanel1.DataContext = item;
```

and the binding is working fine. If I replace my current binding source object with another one, I have to manually set this by typing again the datacontext binding:

```
item = new MyClass();
stackPanel1.DataContext = item;
item1 = new MyClass();
.
. //manipulate item1
.
if (item1 is ok)
   item=item1;
   stackPanel1.DataContext = item;
```

Is there a better way to replace my source object and have all the associated bindings updated?

Comment: First, setting `stackPanel1.DataContext = item1;` is not a binding. It's just setting a property. Then, the `DataContext="{Binding}"` in XAML is useless, since you set the DataContext in code.

Comment: `I'm totally new to C# and WPF` - these are too much to learn together. You'd better get solid on C# first, do some Console Applications so you can get comfortable with the framework and language, before attempting to do anything in WPF which is a complex framework in itself not suitable for unexperienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `stackPanel1.DataContext = item;`, you are ***setting*** the property, not ***binding*** it.

When you *set* the property, you are setting it equal to an instance of the object. When you *bind* it, you are telling it it will be getting its value from some other location, so look in that location anytime it needs to get the value.

Providing your class that contains the bound properties implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), then the UI will be alerted anytime a bound property changes, which causes the binding to get reevaluated.

For example, if you had set the `DataContext` initially with

```
MyWindow.DataContext = this;
```

where `this` was your Window, and your Window had a propety of type `MyClass` called `Item`, then you could bind the `DataContext` using the following

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Item}" ...>
```

and anytime you updated the property `Item`, your StackPanel's `DataContext` would also update (providing you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)).

If you're interested, I like to blog about beginner concepts in WPF, and you may be interested in checking out my article [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/), which is a very simple explanation of what the `DataContext` is and how it's used.

To summarize, WPF has two layers: the UI layer and the Data Layer. The `DataContext` is the data layer, and when you write `{Binding SomeProperty}`, you are actually binding to the data layer. Typically you set the data layer (`DataContext`) once in your code behind, and then use Bindings in your XAML to make your UI layer display information from the data layer.

(You may also be interested in checking out my [Simple MVVM Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/), which contains a very simple working code sample, and illustrates some examples of how `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented and how the UI layers and Data layers can be completely separate)

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `CurrentItem` property in your MainWindow (or UserControl or whatever it is) and also implement `INotifyPropertyChange` for that property. Then set

```
DataContext = this;
```

in the MainWindow's constructor and bind like this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.Title}"
```

Now whenever you set

```
var item = new MyClass();
...
CurrentItem = item;
```

the binding will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataContext="{Binding}"
```

and

```
stackPanel1.DataContext = item;
```

Both do basically the same thing.  The difference being that one is done in XAML and the other is in code.  While the first example would allow binding to be updated given a binding parent the second one must be updated every time you want to change what the stackpanel is attached to.  IMHO you should create a common binding parent to bind against.  This would allow you to change the child bindings without having to set the context everytime.

```
<StackPanel Name="parentPanel">
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" DataContext="{Binding Path=Child}">
            <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>


parent = new ParentClass();
parent.Child= new MyClass();
parentPanel.DataContext = parent ;
```

Now if notify property changed was created on ParentClass correctly you can changing the binding for the child stack panel

```
parent.Child= new NewClass();
```